# cakephp 3 fetch all by using table.*

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using cakePHP3 query builder to fetch records from two tables using following query, where I want all columns from table1 and selected columns from table2:

```
$this->loadModel('Table1');
$Table1 = $this->Table1->find('all', array('fields' => array('Table1.*'),'conditions'=>$conditions,'order'=>array('Table1.id'=>'DESC')))->contain(['Table2']);
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `Table1__*` FROM Table1 Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 Table2 ON ' at line 1
```

I am new to CakePHP3.

Comment: please refer to the correct syntax : `$this->Table1->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => ‘table1’,
            'alias' => ‘table’,
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                ‘table1.id = table2.id’
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'fields' => array(‘table1.*’, ‘table2.field1, table2.field2’),
));`

Comment: Using your code I am getting this error : `Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `Table1__*`, Table2.field1, Table2.field2 AS Table2__field1, Prod' at line 1`

Comment: Looks like CakePHP can't handle `.*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not use query builder?

there are many ways to do that

```
$query= $this->Table1->find('all') 
    ->where($conditions)
    ->order(['Table1.id'=>'DESC'])
    ->contain(['Table2' => [
            'fields' => ['field1', 'field2']
        ]
    ]);
```

or

```
$query= $this->Table1->find('all') 
    ->select($this->Table1) // selects all the fields from Table1
    ->select(['Table2.field1', 'Table2.field2']) // selects some fields from Table2
    ->where($conditions)
    ->order(['Table1.id'=>'DESC'])
    ->contain(['Table2']);
```

or

```
$query= $this->Table1->find('all') 
    ->where($conditions)
    ->order(['Table1.id'=>'DESC'])
    ->contain(['Table2' => function($q) {
             return $q->select(['field1', 'field2']);
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Not necessary in this case though, all fields of `Table1` would be selected anyways. Sound smore like the OP is looking for limiting the fields of the containment, ie `Table2`.

Comment: @ndm in fact.  I used `select($this->Table1)` to avoid having all the fields from Table2

Comment: Yeah, but that will cause the association to not be included in the results, which doesn't make too much sense ;) As far as I understand the OP wants some specific fields from `Table2`.

Comment: Yeah now I see that I misreaded the question and you're probably right

Answer (score -2):

**Assuming the correct relationship between tables**

Example conditions array

```
$conditions = ['Table2.id' > 1];
```

**Selecting Rows From A Table**

```
 $table1 = $this->Table1->find()->select(['Table1.*'])->where($conditions)->contain(['Table2'])->order(['Table1.id'=>'DESC'])->toArray();
```

OR

```
$table1 => $this->Table1->find('all', array(
    'contain' => ['Table2'],
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'fields' => ['Table1.*'],
    'order' => ['Table1.id'=>'DESC']
));
```

here you have more info about [queryBuilder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table)

Comment: Even after changing the query as suggested by you (@Jacek), I am still getting the same error! :(